# Modal implementation that doesn't close when the mouse is released on the backdrop (but only when the backdrop is clicked)

Tags: javascript, css, html, w3c

I have a small issue in my project - I have a modal that closes when the backdrop is pressed. The problem is that if I, for example, hold my mouse to select text and drag the mouse out of the modal, when I release it, the modal closes, because the backdrop has been "pressed".

This small demo on w3schools shows the issue. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal

[image]

In this small demo the code that closes the modal when clicking on the backdrop is obviously this function:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

How would this have to be implemented for it to close when the backdrop is pressed, but NOT when selecting text as shown in the screenshot above.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this would be to change the listener from `onclick` to `onmousedown`.
The explanations is that the listener will fire when you start clicking, so it doesn't matter where you move next.

```
window.onmousedown = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

**Edit**

If you really want to hide the modal once the user released the mouse, you can store the source of the click when pressing "down" and hide it when pressing "up".
Although in this case the modal will hide if the user starts to click outside the modal and releases the mouse in the modal.

```
var clickOnModal = false;
window.onmousedown = function(event) {
  clickOnModal = event.target == modal;
}
window.onmouseup = function() {
  if (clickOnModal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: better on `mouseup` event rather than `mousedown`

Comment: I agree that I would typically recommend using `mouseup` rather than `mousedown`. However in this case gfels wants the modal to NOT close when they are pressing on the modal and releasing on the backdrop. This is why using mousedown should solve this particular issue.

Comment: Thanks, but feels buggy if the modal closes when the user hasn't released the mouse yet.

Comment: Following your feedback, I've added an extra piece of code that shows how you would keep the same behavior while closing the modal on mouseup.